# What is the purpose of the esm directories in the Angular 2 modules?

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular2 RC4:

```
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

and I am using JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2. When I reference Angular2 directives the IDE helpfully offers to import the package in which the directive is defined. Unfortunately the IDE is finding multiple definitions of the directives which means that I have to choose the correct one from a list that is provided. Occasionally I will choose the "wrong" one and I'll end up with a large number of compilation errors. As I've come to learn, the wrong package is always/normally the one in an Angular2 distribution directory containing an `esm` subfolder.

Upon inspection of any `esm` folder it's contents closely mimic those of the sibling `src` folder (for instance):

```
@angular
  common
  + esm
    + src
      + directives
      + facade
      + form-deprecated
      + location
      + pipes
        common_directives.d.ts
        common_directives.js
        common_directives.js.map
        common_directives.metadata.json
        directives.d.ts
        ...
        pipes.js
        pipes.js.map
  + src
    + directives
    + facade
    + form-deprecated
    + location
    + pipes
      common_directives.d.ts
      common_directives.js
      common_directives.js.map
      common_directives.metadata.json
      directives.d.ts
      ...
      pipes.js
      pipes.js.map
```

**Question 1:** What is the purpose of the `esm` directories and why are these  provided in the distribution?

**Question 2:** As an Angular2 application developer do I have need of the files in these directories?

**Question 3:** If "No" to question 2 can I safely remove these from my project and/or is there a way to make IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 ignore these folders?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22746

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Question 1**: The `esm` folder contains the library written in pure **ES2015** (or **ES6**) module syntax. There are two main community created flavours of module in JavaScript-land, **AMD** and **CommonJS**, but ES2015 module is the first time a module syntax is actually part of the language. Code written in ES6 modules is future-proof: the syntax is nicer, cyclic dependencies are supported and modules export bindings rather than values. ES2015 module is more efficient than the other formats and can facilitate the creation of **smaller bundle size** through **tree-shaking technique**, i.e., importing just the bits you need instead of importing the whole thing. The community has already created tools that take advantage of the ES2015 module. As an example, the [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/) library is a JavaScript module bundler that uses tree-shaking technique to generate smaller bundles.

So, why the Angular team has included the `esm` distribution? Well, although nowadays the browsers don't fully support ES2015 syntax, you can use tools like rollup.js to take full advantage of the ES2015 module syntax to produce a super lean bundle of your application.

**Question 2**: Like I said before, you can (or must) use the `esm` directory to generate a smaller bundle of your application using rollup.js  library for example.

**Question 3**: You don't need to remove anything. `esm` directory is your best friend when you have to generate a bundle of your application for production.

An excellent reference for all of it is the [rollup.js wiki page](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki). Take a look.

You can also read the excellent article [Building and Angular 2 Application for Production](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/) that shows how to use rollup.js and tree-shaking.

** *Bonus* **: Inspecting a `package.json` of a library you can see if it has included a ES2015 version. Just look for the `jsnext:main` property. For more details about it you can read the [rollup - jsnext:main](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/jsnext:main) documentation.

Comment: AFAIK webpack 2 will support tree-shaking as well \o/